# Design for client and printing

Tags: print-design

I have a client who wants me to design a lettered graphic for the back side of his boat (18” x 72”)and he wants me to handle the printing-this includes finding the right printing material that can handle saltwater. So my question is, should I be the one handling the printing and finding the right material for it or should the client do this?

Answer (score 3):

It all depends upon what you agree upon with the client.

There's nothing that states you *can't* find vendors to create the decal (or whatever).

It's up to you to decide if you *want* to find vendors. That typically means you deal with the vendor, pay for the product, and then pass on the cost to the client (with a markup).

If you don't wish to handle the production aspect, you are free to decline. Or at least explain to the client you don't/won't handle production. You will only create the artwork prepared for production.